# Enum String values - Binary Operator cannot be applied to operands of type Bool and String

Tags: ios, swift, enums

```
enum DeviceiPad: String {
    case iPadAir = "iPadAir"
    case iPadAir2 = "iPadAir2"
}

func adjustFontsForDevices() {
    let modelName = UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName

    //iPad size adjustments
    guard modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadAir.rawValue ||
        DeviceiPad.iPadAir2.rawValue 
        else {return}
    do {
        adjustCountTitles()
        }
```

modelName calls a String. I'd like to check whether or not that string matches either of two enum raw values (also Strings).

For some reason, Xcode throws this error:
[image: Binary operator || cannot be applied to operands Bool and String]

- Don't let `guard` throw you if you're not familiar with it. Error is the same with `if`
- The `guard` works if there's only one of the string values. Adding the second throws the error.

Been hammering away for a bit trying to figure out why it would see a String value as Bool. Also searched for a bit, but not seeing this issue elsewhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you need is a switch

Comment: For the person that voted this down, please provide reasoning. Searched for a bit and found no answer for this. Think it could be helpful for others.

Comment: Thanks, Leo. A switch would further duplicate code here when I'm running the same method calls for any of the conditions. I'm a fan of switches, but don't think this is where they fit.

Comment: This is not true. you can have multiple case conditions grouped in a single case

Comment: Ah, fair point. Forgot about that.

Comment: Implemented your suggestion below, Leo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A little fix

First of all this

```
let modelName = UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName
```

becomes this

```
let modelName = UIDevice.currentDevice().model
```

### Answer

Next this

```
guard modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadAir.rawValue || DeviceiPad.iPadAir2.rawValue else { return }
```

becomes this

```
guard modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadAir.rawValue || modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadAir2.rawValue else { return }
```

### Update: Testing if your modelName is a value of DeviceiPad

Looking at the comment below you ask how to quickly check if modelName is a value of DeviceiPad.

Of course you want something to **avoid** this

```
guard
    modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadAir.rawValue ||
    modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadAir2.rawValue ||
    modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadMini.rawValue ||
    modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadMini2.rawValue ||
    modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadMini3.rawValue ||
    modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadMini4.rawValue else { return }
```

You can simply write

```
guard let model = DeviceiPad(rawValue: modelName) else { return }
```

In this case if `modelName` does represent the rawValue of a case of `DeviceiPad` then the enum value is create and the next line is executed. Otherwise the `else` block is executed.

Comment: Hmmm. There's no way to have a logical OR after the `==` huh?

Comment: As far as your "first of all", I'm using an extension, so that isn't relevant. Thanks though.

Comment: You can have a logical expression (I mean a boolean value) after an `||`. But in you code you put this `DeviceiPad.iPadAir2.rawValue` after the `||` which is a `String`, not a `Bool`.

Comment: Alrighty, makes sense. Was hoping not to have to repeat the `modelName ==` since it's reused. But it appears that's not possible. Thanks for the help.

Comment: expanding this to the bigger enum, it does seem kind of silly to have to repeat. alas.         ```guard modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadAir.rawValue ||
            modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadAir2.rawValue ||
            modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadMini.rawValue ||
            modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadMini2.rawValue ||
            modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadMini3.rawValue ||
            modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadMini4.rawValue```

Comment: @rockiesGrizzly: I updated my answer, please take a look. It could be what you are looking for.

Comment: The addition to @appzYourLife's answer is excellent and idiomatic if all cases are valid. If you only want to test for a certain subset, it won't work. It's not clear what you were looking for from the original question. I've posted an example of how you might clean things up and test for a subset below.

Comment: Thanks, both. Yes, I was originally looking for a subset of the enum. But appz made me think about breaking up the enum further into multiple enums rather than just one for all the devices. Leo also mentioned the switch idea above which I'll probably give a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a swift programmer, but I see this:

```
guard modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadAir.rawValue ||
    DeviceiPad.iPadAir2.rawValue
```

Shouldn't that be

```
guard modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadAir.rawValue ||
    modelName == DeviceiPad.iPadAir2.rawValue
```

You can't simply do `x == y || z` because `z` as a statement on its own is not a boolean value.  That is, the statement looks like this: `(x == y) || z`.  The `z` is all by its lonesome and isn't being compared to anything.  Some languages do allow it, but most do not.

Comment: Yeah appzYourLife suggested the same below. Was hoping to not have to duplicate the `modelName ==` piece. But it appears that can't be done.

Comment: Nope.  At least, not in swift (or most C-like languages.  Python allows for it).

Comment: Ah. Learned me somethin' today.

Comment: And *that* is what Stack Exchange is for. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clean up if statement, and there's a logical grouping to those device types, you could add a static method on the `DeviceiPad` enum.

```
enum DeviceiPad:String {
    case iPadAir  = "iPadAir"
    case iPadAir2 = "iPadAir2"
    case iPad1 = "iPad"

    static func isSpecialDevice(modelName:String) -> Bool
    {
        guard let model = DeviceiPad(rawValue: modelName) else
        {
            return false
        }

        switch model
        {
        case iPadAir, iPadAir2:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

And then later you'd just use:

```
guard DeviceiPad.isSpecialDevice(modelName) else
{
   return
}
```

Comment: Your `isSpecialDevice` func could also be a `computed property` defined like this `var isSpecial: Bool { return [iPadAir, iPadAir2].contains(self) }`

Comment: The OP would have to successfully convert and bind the modelName string to the enum type first, but otherwise yeah, that's a very nice and clean way to group enum cases.

Comment: Yes, the code outside of the `enum` would look like this `if DeviceiPad(rawValue: modelName)?.isSpecial { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the code above for focus on the comparison. But with a bigger enum, I worked on [Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus)' suggestion above to try a switch. It works and is fairly clean, so I thought I'd add it as an option here since it handles a larger list of enums well and allows for different cases...

```
    switch modelName {
    case DeviceiPad.iPadAir.rawValue,
    DeviceiPad.iPadAir2.rawValue,
    DeviceiPad.iPadMini.rawValue,
    DeviceiPad.iPadMini2.rawValue,
    DeviceiPad.iPadMini3.rawValue,
    DeviceiPad.iPadMini4.rawValue:
        adjustCountTitles()
    case DeviceiPad.iPadPro.rawValue:
        adjustCountNumbers()
    default: break
    }
```